# Computing the unit group of a residue ring

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm interested in understanding why $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/8\mathbb{Z}[i])^*\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (I have confirmed this by looking at element orders). This is of course the group of units in the ring $\mathcal{O}_K/8\mathcal{O}_K$ for $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

The literature on problems like this seems pretty scarce; the only real article I've found is [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2003-72-243/S0025-5718-03-01474-1/S0025-5718-03-01474-1.pdf).

Is there a simple way of understanding the specific example above without resorting to looking at individual element orders? I see that $(\mathbb{Z}[i]/8\mathbb{Z}[i])^*\cong ((\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})[i])^*$, but it's not clear how to proceed from there.

Comment: Considering all powers of $2$ at once, this is a question about the structure of the unit group of $\mathcal{O}_{K,2}$, the completion at the prime $2$. Understanding the unit group of local fields is a very, very, very, well understood problem, and you can find ways to understand it in almost any algebraic number theory book. The group $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_{K,2}$ is isomorphic to $\mu_4 \oplus (\mathbf{Z}_2)^2$, and is topologically generated by $i$, $1+\pi^3$ and $1+\pi^4$ where $\pi = 1+i$.

Comment: Then (easily) $(\mathcal{O}_K/2^m \mathcal{O}_K)^{\times} = \mathbf{Z}/4 \mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{m-1} \mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{m-2} \mathbf{Z}$ for any $m \ge 2$.

Comment: @user655377 Could you expand these thoughts and post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@nguyenquangdo,

I haven't bothered to read your post, which seems to make a meal of this simple problem. Obviously "the completion at $2$" refers to the completion at the unique prime above 2. There is nothing global at all about this question. I'm surprised you seem confused by the well-known fact that the group of units in (the ring of integers in) a local field is isomorphic to the roots of unity plus(the abstract group) $\mathbf{Z}^{[L:\mathbf{Q}_p]}_p$. This is a basic and easy statement you can deduce using the p-adic logarithm. I recommend thinking about what I actually wrote a little more instead of assuming I am doing something different. Certainly I am making no false identifications; to find generators $1 + \pi^3$ and $1 + \pi^4$ of the copy of $\mathbf{Z}^2_2$ in $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_{K,\pi}$ requires some basic skills which can be found [say] in Serre's local fields book.

OK, the OP's request: Since i'm typing this with one hand with a baby on the other, I will just give hints for an elementary approach with obscures a little the general argument. Hopefully you can fill in the details for yourself. Let $\pi = 1+i$.

1. Any element of $(\mathcal{O}/2^m \mathcal{O})^{\times}$ is $1 + \pi^n \bmod \pi^{n+1}$ for some $n$.
   Certainly any element of this group is of $2$-power order.
2. If $x = 1 + \pi^n \bmod \pi^{n+1}$, then $x^2 = 1 + \pi^{n+2} \bmod \pi^{n+3}$ if $n \ge 3$.
3. From 1 and 2 you can easily determine the orders of the elements $1 + \pi^3$ and $1 + \pi^4$ to be $2^{m-1}$ and $2^{m-2}$ respectively, and that they generate distict subgroups.
   Slightly more work shows that they generate the entire subgroup of units $1 \bmod \pi^3$. (One approach, given any element $x = 1 + \pi^n \mod \pi^{n+1}$ with $n \ge 3$, show that dividing by the correct power of either $1 + \pi^3$ or $1 + \pi^4$ you can increase the value of $n$.)
4. Finally, $i$ has order $4$ for $m \ge 2$, and you can check that $i$ generates $(\mathcal{O}/\pi^3 \mathcal{O})^{\times}$. Then it follows that every element of the original group can be written as a unique power of $i$ times something which is $1 \bmod \pi^3$.  I believe you will find that gives exactly the answer written in my original comments.

Comment: (+1) The content of the post is obviously good. Do you mind if I ask though why you're always so abrasive? It seems like every post/comment you make has some tacit accusation of shocking idiocy. You clearly like to encourage people to think more carefully/deeply about the questions they ask/the answers they post--it'll probably be more effective if you aren't always rhetorically surprised at how dumb they are. Again, thanks for the addition of nice content to the site (sincerely)!

Comment: @AlexYoucis +1. I would be more forgiving of myself and say that I am more directly abrasive in response to (mistaken) criticisms of my comments (e.g. in this case) or hubris more generally, but I don't dispute you general comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So it looks like that approach works if for example we were to take $K=\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ and $p=3$. Does it also work for any imaginary quadratic extension whose ring of integers is a PID? Is there anything useful one can say about either 1) the case of a non-PID, or 2) the case where $p$ does not ramify in the extension?

Comment: @rogerl being a PID is irrelevant, this method will work for all primes and all number fields, and the answer will only depend on the completion of that number field at the primes above $p$ (which is slightly more refined information than how $p$ factors but there is still only finitely many possibilities for each degree).

Comment: To give a down to earth example, if $d \equiv -1 \bmod 8$, and $A = \mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is the ring of integers of $K = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, then

$$(A/2^m A)^{\times}$$

does not depend on $d$ (and is computed above when $d = -1$). Another random example, if $d \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ and $A$ is the ring of integers of $K$ (so $2$ splits in $A$), then

$$(A/2^m A)^{\times} \simeq (\mathbf{Z}/2^m \mathbf{Z})^{\times}
\oplus (\mathbf{Z}/2^m \mathbf{Z})^{\times}.$$

Comment: @Furlo Roth.     
Sorry for my late comment, but I've been away for some time. You write : "I'm surprised you seem confused by the well-known fact that the group of units in (the ring of integers in) a local field is isomorphic to the roots of unity plus(the abstract group) $Z_p^{[L:Q_p]}$". And thanks for the reference to Serre's classic. But this was not my point. I stressed that you computed the quotient (group of local units mod $2^k$), whereas the OP asked for the unit group of the quotient (global ring mod $2^k$).

Comment: Is this "to make a meal of a simple problem which has nothing to do with a global question" (approximative citation) ? Also,I would be glad to know the opinion of the OP

Comment: @nguyenquangdo, I'm really confused why you are struggling to understand this. Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote a global ring of integers and let $\mathcal{O}_2$ denote $\projlim \mathcal{O}/2^n \mathcal{O}$, which is just the product of the completions of $\mathcal{O}$ at the primes above $2$. Then you do realize that there is a canonical isomorphism

$$\mathcal{O}/2^n \mathcal{O} = \mathcal{O}_2/2^n \mathcal{O}_2$$

right? Hence

$$(\mathcal{O}/2^n \mathcal{O})^{\times} = (\mathcal{O}_2/2^n \mathcal{O}_2)^{\times}$$

Is computing the right hand side not a local question???

Comment: @nguyenquangdo, 
there is an obvious surjection $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_2 \rightarrow (\mathcal{O}_2/2^n \mathcal{O}_2)^{\times}$ (please tell me you understand this). The first group is generated by $i$, $1 + \pi^3$ and $1 + \pi^4$ by standard methods, and the images of these elements are also easy to understand as I have now explained several times including in the answer above.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo, you seem to repeatedly claim that I am computing $G/2^n G$ where
 $G = \mathcal{O}^{\times}_2$ which obviously I am not, since then the answer would be different. (I say you "seem to be claiming" because honestly I don't know what is confusing you.)

Comment: @Furlo Roth. Sorry, I made several times the same "misprint", $O_2/2^k$ instead of $O_2/1+ (2^k)$. Please do the mental correction and let us go on. I agree of course with $(O/2^k)^* \cong (O_2/2^k)^*$, but an iso. can be read in two ways. You chose to follow the RHS in order to take advantage of the "very, very well known" structure of the local units, but a Beotian could view this as "making a meal" and prefer to start from scratch on the global LHS.

Comment: If you had "bothered" to read my post and "think a little more about what I actually wrote" you would have seen that I just gave an expansion limited to the $2^k$-th level instead of taking the whole projective limit. Your local solution may be shorter, but it only looks so, as you say yourself that it requires "some basic skills", thank you again. I devised my global one so as to stick to the "retro" approach of the OP, who computed the orders of all elements at hand. In the end, the main point is that your final result does not coincide with mine ...

Comment: ... (and the OP's, although he appears to have changed his mind). Of course non functorial calculations such as here are always prone to errors, and as an expert, you're certainly aware of the mess that the prime $2$ can sometimes induce. This is the reason why I wrote down the details for everybody to check in case of doubt. The particular feature is the decomposition of $5$ which yields the product $\mathbf Z/2^{k-1}\times \mathbf Z/2^{k-1}$. It appears already in $\mathbf Z$ when computing $(\mathbf Z/p^k)^*$ (which is cyclic for $p$ odd, and of type ($2, 2^{k-2}$) for $p=2$ and $k$$>2$)...

Comment: ... or when determining the structure of ${\mathbf Z_p}^∗$. This feature doesn't seem to appear in the general outline of your local approach. Besides, when replacing $\mathbf Z$ by $\mathbf Z[i]$, a lattice of rank 2 appears.  But, since you don't give details, I can only guess. EDIT: In the very first comment, read ${O_2}^∗/1+(2^k)$.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo "The particular feature is the decomposition of 5..." --- well, if you do the problem in a stupid way, quite possibly. The OP has expressed interest in the structure of $(\mathcal{O}/2^n \mathcal{O})^{\times}$ for the ring of integers in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ for other $D$. From the local approach, this obviously only depends on the decomposition of $2$ in $K$, and so using that the Gaussian integers are a PID and that $5$ factors in a particular way suggests an excessively labyrinthine solution.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo "In the end, the main point is that your final result does not coincide with mine ..". Yes, and the comment I wrote down in $5$ minutes about $3$ weeks ago --- several days before you wrote your answer --- is 100% correct.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo And finally taking a look at what you wrote, it is full of nonsense. You say that if $x \in U_{r} - U_{r+1}$ that $x^2 \in U_{r+1} - U_{r+2}$, when rather the key point is that  $x^2 \in U_{r+2} - U_{r+3}$. You claim that $5$ has order $2^{2k-2}$  when it actually has order $2^{k-1}$. Your (false) claim would imply that $U_2/U_{2k}$ is cyclic, but instead you bizarrely deduce that $U_2/U_{2k} = (\mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1})^2$. Finally, you claim $U_1 = (\pm 1) \times U_2$, which is also rubbish. The map $U_1 \rightarrow U_1/U_2$ doesn't split (for starters, $-1 \in U_2$).

Comment: @nguyenquangdo To correct your answer by following my explanation above, you see that any element of $U_3 - U_4$ has order $2^{m-1}$, and any element of $U_4 - U_5$ has order $2^{m-2}$, and any such pair of elements will generate $U_3$. Finally, $U_1 \rightarrow U_1/U_3$ does split, since $i$ generates $U_1/U_3$. Thus 

$$U_1 \simeq U_1/U_3 \times U_3 = (\mathbf{Z}/4 \mathbf{Z}) \oplus (\mathbf{Z}/2^{m-1} \mathbf{Z}) \oplus (\mathbf{Z}/2^{m-2} \mathbf{Z})$$ 
 
 for any $m \ge 2$.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo It looks to me as though your approach will work but has some errors. Perhaps you could correct those in your answer. Also, I did not (as you wrote above) change my mind. The decomposition I wrote in my original post is correct. Thanks for your alternative proof; I see the parallels between what you wrote and what FurloRoth wrote.

Comment: @ Furlo Roth. Since you look unable to  discuss without "some tacit accusation of shocking idiocy", as @Alex Youcis puts it, I'll stop here.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo I thank you for your work, and don't blame you for stopping here...

Comment: @Rogerl. Perhaps you should first point out where I made errors, and I'll correct them if necessary. I must confess I'm too tired of this thread to go all over again.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo The comments from Furlo Roth from an hour ago I think point out where your errors are, though in an unnecessarily combative way.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo. I have no objections to idiocy. It's your extreme level of hubris that I find galling. "Perhaps you should first point out where I made errors" --- what twaddle. As rogerl says, just read the comments I made which point out at least three of them.

Comment: Mother of god, what have been I tagged to. I'm just going to stay out of this one chaps. Have fun. I will say that the words "twaddle" Furlo Roth and "Beotian" @nguyen  are quite amusing--so thanks for that you two!

Comment: @Rogerl I have rewritten the end of §§1 and 2 of my edit for more clarity. Also gave a proof of the direct sum decomposition.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I attempted some "friendlier" answers under the username "Lycurgus cup" on mathoverflow. I have to admit that I find the trench warfare here about technical points of algebraic number theory over 1 point answers for which the OP has long since departed to be much more satisfying.

Comment: @user670344 Actually I'm still here. I seem unable to find your post(s) on mathoverflow; either I'm incompetent or search by username is broken. Can you post a link?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Revised answer after discussion with the OP.
EDIT 2 after "discussion" with @user655377

Here is a direct approach, not appealing to local fields (*). In order to answer also to @Shimrod, let me start with a general imaginary quadratic field $K$ in which the prime $2$ is totally ramified (this is the meaning of the condition "$2$ divides the discriminant"), i.e. $(2)$  is the square of a prime ideal of $\mathfrak O_K=\mathfrak O$, say $(2)=P^2$, so that $\mathfrak O/2^k=\mathfrak O/P^{2k}$ for all $k\ge 1$. The natural surjective ring homomorphism $\mathfrak O/P^{2k}\to \mathfrak O/P^2$ for $k\ge 2$ induces a homomorphism of groups $f_k :(\mathfrak O/P^{2k})^*\to (\mathfrak O/P^2)^*$, and we aim to determine its kernel and cokernel. It will be convenient to write $[a]_k$ for the class of $a$ in $\mathfrak O/P^{2k}$.

1) Now add the hypothesis that $\mathfrak O$ is a PID (which is the case here with $\mathbf Z[i]$), and denote $P=(\pi)$. Then $[a]_1$ is invertible iff $\pi \nmid a$, iff $[a]_k$ is invertible too (just apply Bezout's thm. in $\mathfrak O$). It follows that $f_k$ is surjective. Besides it is straightforward that Ker$f_k= (1+(\pi^2)/1+(\pi^{2k}),\times)$, and we'll compute its order by introducing the descending filtration $..(\pi^n)> (\pi^{n+1})>...$ and its successive quotients  $(\pi^n)/(\pi^{n+1})$. The map  $x \to x-1$ induces isomorphisms $(1+(\pi^n)/1+(\pi^{n+1}),\times)\cong (\pi^n)/(\pi^{n+1})\cong(\mathbf F_2,+)$, where $\mathbf F_2$ is the residual field  at $(\pi)$ (just check that $(xy-1)-(x-1)-(y-1)$ $=(x-1)(y-1))$.  It follows immediately that  Ker$f_k$ has order $2^{2k-2}$. It remains to compute the order of $(\mathfrak O/\pi^2)^*$ following the same steps: the map $(\mathfrak O/\pi^2)^* \to (\mathfrak O/\pi)^*$ is surjective, but $(\mathfrak O/\pi)^*=\mathbf F_2^*=(1)$, so $(\mathfrak O/\pi^2)^*$ has the same order $2$ as the kernel  $(\pi)/(\pi^2)$, and finally $(\mathfrak O/\pi^{2k})^*$ has order $2^{2k-1}$. So we have an exact sequence of abelian $2$-primary groups $1\to$ Ker$f_k \to (\mathfrak O/\pi^{2k})^* \to (\mathfrak O/\pi^2)^* \to 1$ where the comparison of the orders shows at once that the middle term admits an element of order $2$ not contained in the left kernel, in other words, the sequence splits.

2) To get hold of the structure of $(\mathfrak O/\pi^{2k})^*$ we need more information on the quadratic field $K$. In your case, $K=\mathbf Q (i)$ and we can take $\pi=1-i$. To simplify notations, denote by $U_n$ the multiplicative group $1+(\pi^n)$. Then our previous Ker$f_k$ is just $U_2/U_{2k}$. For $r\ge 2$ and $x\in U_r - U_{r+1}$, the binomial formula shows that $x^2 \in U_{r+2} - U_{r+3}$. Take in particular $x=5=(2+i)(2-i) \in U_2 - U_3$ and denote by $5_{2k}$ its image in $U_2/U_{2k}$. By repeated application of the binomial formula, $5_{2k}$ has order $2^{k-1}$, and $U_2/U_{2k}=$ Ker$f_k$ has order $2^{2k-2}$ by the calculation  in 1) above. Summarizing, Ker$f_k = <2+i>_{2k} \times <2-i>_{2k}$, where the two factors are permuted by complex conjugation, so that Ker$f_k
 \cong \mathbf Z/2^{k-1} \times \mathbf Z/2^{k-1}$ and we have a split exact sequence $0\to \mathbf Z/2^{k-1} \times \mathbf Z/2^{k-1} \to (\mathfrak O/(\pi^{2k}))^* \to \mathbf Z/2 \to 0$ (see 1) above). In your case here, $(\mathbf Z[i]/2^k)^*\cong \mathbf Z/2 \times \mathbf Z/2^{k-1}\times \mathbf Z/2^{k-1}$. For $k=3$ one recovers your "retro" formula.

WARNING. My solution is erroneous, as shown by @user670344. *Errare humanum est, perseverare diabolicum.*

Comment: A few questions: 1) why does dividing out $\mu_K$ simplify the process, and where in the discussion did you actually use the fact that you had done so?, 2) I don't see why $x\mapsto x-1$ gives an isomorphism. The given equation shows only that the difference between $xy-1$ and $(x-1)+(y-1)$ lies in $(\pi^4)$, unless I'm missing something. 3) Why is $2\mathfrak O/4\mathfrak O\cong\mathbb{F}_2$? Doesn't it have four elements?

Comment: 1) Concerning "dividing out $\mu_K$", you're right, I wonder why I did it. Since $O$ is a ring, you can only take a quotient modulo an ideal. If you cosider only the additive group structure, $O$ has no torsion. If you consider the multiplicative group $O^*$, you follow the same wrong track as @user655377. I'll edit that. But then, in the final result, a factor is missing in comparison with your formula. Where did you get that formula ?

Comment: 2) It's $1+ (\pi ^n)/1+(\pi^{n+1})$. I'll edit that too.  3) Same remark.

Comment: I got the formula by actually writing down the group elements and looking at element orders (I know, so retro). Your formula of $(\mathbf Z/4)\times \mathbf Z/2$ must be wrong: there are more than eight elements in this group, such as $(2r+1)+(2s)i$ for $0\le r, s\le 3$.

Comment: And note that when you changed the filtration in 2), you introduced more levels in the filtration, so there are now $2k-2$ copies of $\mathbf F{2}$. So that at least produces the correct number of elements. But I think your conclusion that the quotient $(\pi^2)/(\pi^{2k})\cong \mathbf F{2}^{2k-2}$ is still wrong; there's no particular reason, I think, to assume that the quotients combine in that way. Certainly if you just work in the integers, and look at $(2)/(8)$ compared to $(2)/(4)$ and $(4)/(8)$, you get $\mathbf{Z}/4$ for the first quotient.

Comment: First, you're right about the levels of the new filtration, there are now 2k-2 successive quotients (I had not even checked, I hate this kind of non functorial calculations). Second, how do these quotients combine ? I got confused with the notation, thinking of Ker $f_k$ as a cyclic group. But no, the multiplicative group $1+P^2$ "behaves like" (think of the log) the additive group $P^2$, which is itself of finite index in the additive group $O$, which is a $\mathbf Z$-free module of rank 2. So we recover your formula. What do you think ?

Comment: So the general formula for $(\mathfrak{O}/2^k\mathfrak{O})^*$ for $k>1$ seems to be $\mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1}\times \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-2}\times \mathbf{Z}/4$ (derived empirically).

Comment: Sorry, don't understand how the fact that $P^2$ is of finite index in a free $\mathbf{Z}$ module gives the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92645/discussion-between-nguyen-quang-do-and-rogerl).

Comment: Even though this answer has undergone quite a few revisions, it unfortunately still contains many inaccuracies and  needs to be almost entirely redone. Here are some particular issues:

Comment: **Problem**: You say that $5 \in U/U_{2k}$ has order $2^{k-1}$. In fact, $5 \in U_4$ has order $2^{k-2}$.

Comment: **Non-sequitur**: From the factorization $5 = (2+i)(2-i)$ you claim without argument that $U_2$ is generated by $(2+i)$ and $(2-i)$ --- how does the factorization of $5$ play any role in this at all? In fact, neither $2+i$ and $2-i$ are even elements of $U_2$, they are in $U_1$. Since you offer no argument for your claim it's hard to see what the mistake in your reasoning is.

Comment: **Non-sequitur**: (as above) The sentence starting "Summarizing" is an (incorrect) assertion without any argument. As said above, the elements are not even in $U_2$. More seriously, even though $2+i$ and $2-i$ both have order $2^{k-1}$ (as it happens), and complex conjugation does permute each factor, they do **not** generate the group $(\mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1})^2$. This can be seen from the fact that their product $5$ has order $2^{k-2}$, which wouldn't happen if your claim was true. They actually generate the group $(\mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1}) \oplus (\mathbf{Z}/2^{k-2})$ of index $4$ inside $U_1$.

Comment: **Problem**: The map $U_1 \rightarrow U_1/U_2$ does not split, rather, as explained by @FurloRoth in the comments to his answer, the map $U_1 \rightarrow U_1/U_3$ splits.

Comment: **More details**: You say "the comparison of the orders shows at once that the middle term admits an element of order 2 not contained in the left kernel". You can't possibly prove splitting by considering orders alone. As it happens, the elements of order $2$ in $U$ form a subgroup $(\mathbf{Z}/2)^3$ generated explicitly by an element of $U_{2n-2} - U_{2n-1}$, an element of $U_{2n-1} - U_{2n}$, and $-1 \in U_2$. These elements all lie in $U_2$, and hence are trivial in $U/U_2$. In particular, the sequence does not split (this was also pointed out by @FurloRoth).

Comment: **Accident**: Your formula $(\mathbf{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1})$ is therefore not proved. However, it turns out also to be the wrong answer for general $k$.  It happens to be correct (and agrees with the computation of @rogerl and Furlo Roth) for $k = 3$, but this is just an accident.

Comment: **Summary**: The factorization of $5$ seems to be a red herring. You can prove directly that $5$ and $2i - 1$ in $U_4 - U_5$ and $U_3 - U_4$ respectively have order $2^{k-1}$ and $2^{k-2}$ and generate $U_3$. The point is that their powers lie in even and odd $U_n - U_{n+1}$ and so the cyclic subgroups generated by these two elements do not intersect. Finally, $U_1 \rightarrow U_1/U_3$ splits, because $i \in U_1$ maps to a generator of $U_1/U_3$. Hence $U_1 = \mathbf{Z}/4 \oplus U_3$ and one recovers the formula of Furlo Roth and @rogerl.

Comment: You are quite right all along (@), and I make a public apology. As you said, the factorization of $5$ was a red herring, which could have been avoided if I had computed the correct order for $5_{2k}$. This is an illustration of how $2$ can be messy !   (@) Where did I use the splitting of $U_1 \to U_1/U_2$ ?

Comment: After computing $U_2$ (not quite correctly), you say "and we have a split exact sequence [$U_2 \rightarrow U_1 \rightarrow U_1/U_2$]... (see 1)" on the preantepenultimate line. It's not obvious how to compute $U_1 = \mathbf{Z}/4 \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-2}$ from $U_2 = \mathbf{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-1} \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2^{k-2}$.

Comment: Right, thank you. By the way, should I delete my answer since it is not correct ? What is the usage at SE ?