# Units in a quotient of a quadratic number ring

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic field. Let $\mathcal O$ be its ring of integers. Suppose that $2$ divides the discriminant of $K$.

What is the structure of the multiplicative group $(\mathcal O /2^k \mathcal O)^\times$?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of this question, asked at almost the same time: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180079/computing-the-unit-group-of-a-residue-ring

Comment: And just as in that case, there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}^{\times}_2 \simeq \mu_{K_2} \oplus (\mathbf{Z}_2)^2$, where $\mu_{K_2}$ denotes the roots of unity in $K_2$, which (under your hypothesis) is either cyclic of order $2$ or of order $4$. Once again, the answer is best understood by learning about local fields.

Comment: Have you tried looking at a specific ring, like, say, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{14}]$, and seeing if it gives you any general insights?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3186089/300700